# mySQL Error 1064 in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I know it may be silly but I've spent 2 hours looking for the error and my deadline is running short. Can you help?

Here's the code

```
create view Children as
select avg(chAvg) as Avg_Children
from
(select CHILDREN.ID,
CHILDREN.PAT_ID,
CHILDREN.GENDER,
DRUGS.DRUG_TYPE,
count(CHILDREN.ID)/count(distinct(CHILDREN.PAT_ID)) as 'chAvg'
from CHILDREN
join PATIENTS
on CHILDREN.PAT_ID = PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID
join CASES
on PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID=CASES.PAT_ID
join DRUGS_TO_CASES
on CASES.CASE_ID = DRUGS_TO_CASES.CASE_ID
join DRUGS
on DRUGS_TO_CASES.DRUG_ID=DRUGS.ID
where DRUGS.DRUG_TYPE = 'tranquillisers'
group by CHILDREN.GENDER)
```

And here's what Workbench says:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19
```

Comment: Can you build a scheme with http://sqlfiddle.com/? Maybe a simple blank is missing?

Comment: Group by clause issue, no aggregate function used in select list or add all columns in group clause

Comment: No luck with fiddle either :( I'm learning sql on the go so I'm not very comfortable when it comes to subquerying

Comment: Guessing parentheses

Comment: Avoid using a view name which is the same as your table name.Also you are missing an alias on that derived table

Comment: Yes! It was the alias indeed! The devil in the details :P Submit your suggestion as an answer if you want so I can upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias on the subquery and try to avoid the same name as the table even if mysql allows it

```
create view VChildren as
select avg(chAvg) as Avg_Children
from
(select CHILDREN.ID,
CHILDREN.PAT_ID,
CHILDREN.GENDER,
DRUGS.DRUG_TYPE,
count(CHILDREN.ID)/count(distinct(CHILDREN.PAT_ID)) as 'chAvg'
from CHILDREN
join PATIENTS
on CHILDREN.PAT_ID = PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID
join CASES
on PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID=CASES.PAT_ID
join DRUGS_TO_CASES
on CASES.CASE_ID = DRUGS_TO_CASES.CASE_ID
join DRUGS
on DRUGS_TO_CASES.DRUG_ID=DRUGS.ID
where DRUGS.DRUG_TYPE = 'tranquillisers'
group by CHILDREN.GENDER)x
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this particular error:

```
mysql> create view Children as
    -> select avg(chAvg) as Avg_Children
    -> from
    -> (select CHILDREN.ID,
    -> CHILDREN.PAT_ID,
    -> CHILDREN.GENDER,
    -> DRUGS.DRUG_TYPE,
    -> count(CHILDREN.ID)/count(distinct(CHILDREN.PAT_ID)) as 'chAvg'
    -> from CHILDREN
    -> join PATIENTS
    -> on CHILDREN.PAT_ID = PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID
    -> join CASES
    -> on PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID=CASES.PAT_ID
    -> join DRUGS_TO_CASES
    -> on CASES.CASE_ID = DRUGS_TO_CASES.CASE_ID
    -> join DRUGS
    -> on DRUGS_TO_CASES.DRUG_ID=DRUGS.ID
    -> where DRUGS.DRUG_TYPE = 'tranquillisers'
    -> group by CHILDREN.GENDER);
ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
mysql>
```